# XNA GameTime before first Update

Tags: xna, game-loop

Using XNA, is it possible to access the GameTime object *before* Update is called for the first time?

Can it be used in the game constructor, Initialize or LoadContent methods?

Comment: Wouldn't you just assume its value is zero anyway?

Comment: I'm curious as to what is your purpose there, if you wish to share.

Comment: I need to pass it to another static class that manages game time as well as other time related things that are specific to the project.  At the moment the first opportunity I have to do this is on the first Update loop, every loop after that the line is redundant.  I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: It's not that big of a deal... It's certainly not going to cause massive frame loss or anything.

Comment: I realise that, but it's not very elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible:

> The GameTime object received by Draw
>   and Update isn't technically owned by
>   anyone, but is instead re-created each
>   Game.Tick and passed to Update and
>   Draw from there.
>
> Internally, Tick fills the value of
>   the Total/ElapsedRealTime properties
>   based off of the current high
>   performance counter value as reported
>   by Stopwatch.GetTimestamp().  If the
>   PC the program is running on does not
>   have a high performance counter, then
>   it returns DateTime.Now.Ticks.
>
> The Game Time properties (as opposed
>   to real-time) also use the
>   Stopwatch.GetTimestamp, however
>   elapsed time since application launch
>   and last frame are computed internally
>   and then filled in before **GameTime is
>   passed to Draw or Update - so there's
>   no external way to compute those
>   values directly.**

Source: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/10587.aspx, bold mine. Also included there are several work arounds, similar to what you've already outlined though.

Comment: Based on this, the main game Update method could probably update the static time manager class mentioned before any subsequent game components needed it, ie before calling base.Update.

Comment: Yes, that is likely, but it still doesn't remove having a line in the Update method which passes gameTime somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with these workarounds and see what works.